# get velue from query PERFORM 1 into temp FROM master_balance where externalkey = 'jknfl12j3' and tenant_record_id = '2' for update;1

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have function, inside the function running postgresql this query :

```
PERFORM 1 into temp FROM master where externalkey = 'jknfl12j3' and tenant = '2' for update;
```

Table structure master :

```
id     externalkey       tenant     balance
1       jknfl12j3          1          100
```

I want to get the balance, can i do that ? possible with `temp.balance` ?

Comment: Are you trying to create a new table or store the result in a PL/pgSQL variable?

Comment: store the result in a PL/pgSQL variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `select` not perform. You also need to declare the variable to hold the balance:

```
...
declare
  l_balance numeric;
begin
  select balance 
      into l_balance
  from master 
  where ...   
  for update;

  ... more code
end;
```

Comment: it's no possible with PERFORM ? because i need lock row so the data still concurrent with PERFORM

Comment: You don't need PERFORM to lock the row.

Comment: select balance 
      into l_balance
  from master 
  where ...   
  for update;

are same with 

perform 1
  from master 
  where ...   
  for update;

is right ?